# Getting different results when doing the Lagrangian of a simple pendulum with different coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

I was just testing out the Lagrangian on the simple pendulum and noticed that I got different results based on how I defined theta.

When defining $\theta$ from the vertical, we have $x=r\sin\theta$ and $y=-r\cos\theta$. Then,
\begin{align}
L&=T-U \\
&=\frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot\theta^2-mgr\cos\theta
\end{align}
Then the Euler-Lagrange equations give,
$$
\frac{g}{r}\sin\theta+\ddot\theta=0\tag{1}
$$

But when defining $\theta$ from the horizontal, we end up with
$$
\frac{g}{r}\cos\theta+\ddot\theta=0\tag{2}
$$

Since (1) and (2) are not the same when considering the small angle approximation, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is *because* of the two different coordinate systems. When defining $\theta$ from the vertical axis, the stable stationary point is when $\theta=0$ which enables the small angle approximation. However, when defining $\theta$ from the horizontal axis, the stable stationary point is at $\theta=90^\circ$ and we cannot use the small angle approximation. Instead, we would have to do [a slightly different small angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation#Angle_sum_and_difference):
$$
\cos\left(\pi/2\pm\theta\right)\approx\cos(\pi/2)\mp\theta\sin(\pi/2)\simeq\mp\theta
$$
which seems to give you the same solution as when considering $\theta$ from vertical axis.